# Getting IllegalStateException when trying to register MultiPartFeature JAX-RS Jersey 2.0

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to register `MultiPartFeature` in the ResourceConfig and I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:270)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:218)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:448)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:309)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:169)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:359)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code I'm doing this is the following:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("ws")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig

{

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Tried the approach using Application sub-class overriding the `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()` method and adding the full-path to `MultiPartFeature` but, no lucky. Same exception.

I'm stuck in this for hours. Please, could you guys help me? What Am I missing?

Comment: In case of application subclass, you need to override getProperties() method and then register your class. It is similar to web.xml

Comment: Another thing, your code is not showing registration of packages which contain jersey resources. Try to add that and then register your MultiPartFeature

Comment: Vikas, thank you for your reply. In fact, I only posted the relevant code, my code is indeed registrating Jersey resources. I kind of solved the problem, I'm not sure yet but it was about incorrect version of dependencies.
But thank you anyway.

Comment: when you remove the multipart line everything is ok ?

Comment: @Ash, yes.
The problem seems to be in the multipart dependence (jars)

Comment: can you share the relevant dependencies from your pom.xml ?